# How to print array key and value using map function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to print the key and value of an array but i can't get it done, what's the best way to do this? but i'd like to use map but any other better method is also ok, I'd also like to be able to track the index of the array.

```
colorArray = [0:0: 'Red', 0:1: 'Blue', 0:2: 'Green', 0:3: 'Orange']
{colorArray.map((val, index) => {
     <div> 
       <div className='value-img' >
         <span>(index+1)"."+val+", "key+", "index<span>
       </div>
    </div>

}
```

and I want the result below

1. Red, 0:0, 0
2. Blue, 0:1, 1
3. Green, 0:2, 2
4. Orange, 0:3, 3

How can I achieve this result above. Thanks

Comment: What you have provided is not valid JavaScript, therefore the question cannot be answered.

Comment: I assume this question should also have the [tag:reactjs] tag, but it's not quite clear from the code given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the array is not syntactically correct. if you wish to maintain the same key-value pair for some reason, it cannot be done with array, you can go for Object

```js
    var colorObj = {['0:0']: 'Red', ['0:1']: 'Blue', ['0:2']: 'Green', ['0:3']: 'Orange'}
    Object.entries(colorObj).map((c)=>console.log(c[0],c[1]))
```

Or better a 2D array.

```js
     var colorArray = [['0:0', 'Red'],['0:1', 'Blue'],['0:2', 'Green'],['0:3', 'Orange']]
    colorArray.map((c)=>console.log(c[0],c[1]))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks it's straigth forward enough I'd prefer 2d array method

Answer (score 0):

For this task you can use Object, instead of Array, so it will utilize `key -> value` pairs. Check inline comments:

```js
// You can use Object instead
// Here we define key -> value pairs
const colorObject = {
  "0:0": "Red",
  "0:1": "Blue",
  "0:2": "Green",
  "0:3": "Orange"
}

// Counter to count iterations
let counter = 0;

// Iterate Object with for loop
// and increase counter each iteration
for(const el in colorObject) {
  // Form your html as you need
  // For now we will just print it to console
  console.log(`
  <div> 
    <div className='value-img' >
      <span>${counter+1} ${colorObject[el]}, ${el}, ${counter}<span>
    </div>
  </div>
  `);
  // Increase counter
  counter++;
}
```